# Updating a Linux app (rsync) - what am I meant to do with .yo files?

Tags: upgrade, man

OS: Linux Mint 18.3

With a view to starting to use `rsync` I wanted to upgrade to the latest version: Synaptic on this machine has version 3.1.1. but the latest stable version is 3.1.3.

So I downloaded the source files and compiled. I was also told that to get up-to-date `man` pages I had to install yodl, which I did.

After `make` (NB I've never done this before to install or update an app) I find that there is an `rsync` executable file in the "expansion" directory (yep, version is indeed 3.1.3), and two .yo files: rsync.yo and rsyncd.conf.yo.

I presume that the thing to do now is to replace the existing 3.1.1 version of `rsync` at /usr/bin/ with the new `rsync`.

But what am I meant to do with these .yo files to ensure that the `man` pages will give instructions about version 3.1.3, not 3.1.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the installation instructions in the `INSTALL` file: as root, run

```
make install
```

This will copy `rsync` to whatever prefix `./configure` used (`/usr/local` by default, so `rsync` will end up in `/usr/local/bin`), and the manpages to the appropriate directory.

Don’t replace your existing binaries. Instead, remove the `rsync` package (if you can).

Comment: Thank you!!! Aha... I had actually, like a a good learner, taken the trouble to read the README and the INSTALL file.  I understood "$ ./configure" "$ make" at the top of INSTALL, but I was thoroughly confused by the next line "# make install".  So thanks for explaining what this means.  One more tiny step on the journey of 1000 miles to Linux knowledge...

Comment: I tried removing the rsync package. Something had to be done because, although /usr/local/bin actually comes before /usr/bin in my PATH, for some reason rsync --version still gives the old version (3.1.1). But the first time I did this I marked "complete removal" in Synaptic, and this meant that Timeshift was removed, MySQL became unusable, etc.!  So I restored using Timeshift (recent image). Obviously rsync is  a major dependency for quite a few things. What's the protocol? I.e. how to get all these big beasts to use the updated version? Or do the 2 versions just have to co-exist?

Comment: PS Oh, the system is now giving 3.1.3 as the version.  And I just went `man rsync`. Difficult to know which version these `man` pages are for because it doesn't say (I suspect things may not have changed much). But at the bottom it gives the date "28 Jan 2018", which suggests this is for 3.1.3.  Maybe Timeshift, MySQL etc. can function OK with the new version ... one might hope so.

Comment: As long as you have `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` in your `PATH` (which is the default setup), programs running `rsync` without an explicit path will use your newer version. Likewise, the default `man` setup will use your manpages rather than the packaged manpages.